# Display div right after previous, but take off of the flow of a document

Tags: css, display

Display div write after previous(as in position:relative) but take off of the flow of a document - so it doesnt affect other div flows and acts like pop up. How to achieve it?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="menu item colaborate">Colaborate</a>
<div class="colab-box hide">
    <textarea rows="10" name="comment" class="colab-input"id="comment </textarea>
    <button class="send-colab">Colaborate</button>
</div><!--colab-box  -->
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
     $('.colaborate').click(function(e) {
        $('.colab-box').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document.body).click(function() {
    $('.colab-box').hide(); });
    $('.colab-box').click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.colab-box{ 
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left: 76%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    width:23%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    background:#fff;
}
```

As you can see on click colab-box is toggled - but as it is relative positioned it taked some space and disorders the order of other elements. If I position it absolute - then I wont know where to exactely as i need it to pop up right after 'Colaborate' button.

Comment: what have you done till now? and add little bit code for catching the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is not a code writing service please add a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the code to affect the other elements in your page you will need to overlay the popup using something like 'absolute' position. If you put a container around the two elements and set it to have a position of 'relative' you can then set the popup to be 'absolute' and give it a specific left value. This will mean that you have to set a fixed width on the button though.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colaborate').click(function(e) {
    $('.colab-box').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document.body).click(function() {
    $('.colab-box').hide();
  });
  $('.colab-box').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.menu.item.colaborate {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.colab-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 80px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  width: 23%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="menu item colaborate">Colaborate</a>
  <div class="colab-box hide">
    <textarea rows="10" name="comment" class="colab-input" id="comment"></textarea>
    <button class="send-colab">Colaborate</button>
  </div>
  <!--colab-box  -->
</div>
```